# Unable to understand the 403 Error from HTML parsing using BeautifulSoup4 with Python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, ssl-certificate, html-parsing, urllib

I am in the Coursera Course Python For Everyone Course and I attempted one of the questions from the [textbook](https://www.py4e.com/html3/12-network):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'https://www.py4e.com/book.htm'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

I don't understand the error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

But according to the full error, it starts @Line 18. From reading other SO and this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50585069/9895280) that it probably has something to do with the SSL certificate and how the website thinks I'm a bot.
Why doesn't the code work?

Comment: You can [add a header](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.add_header) in your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.py4e.com/book.htm'
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})

Link = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup =BeautifulSoup(Link.content,"lxml")

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

Output:

```
http://amzn.to/1KkULF3
book/index.htm
http://amzn.to/1KkULF3
http://amzn.to/1hLcoBy
http://amzn.to/1KkV42z
http://amzn.to/1fNOnbd
http://amzn.to/1N74xLt
http://do1.dr-chuck.net/py4inf/EN-us/book.pdf
http://do1.dr-chuck.net/py4inf/ES-es/book.pdf
https://twitter.com/fertardio
translations/KO/book_009_ko.pdf
http://www.xwmooc.net/python/
http://fanwscu.gitbooks.io/py4inf-zh-cn/
book_270.epub
translations/ES/book_272_es4.epub
https://www.gitbook.com/download/epub/book/fanwscu/py4inf-zh-cn
html-270/
html_270.zip
http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/python-for-informatics/id554638579?mt=13
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~csev/books/py4inf/ibooks//python_for_informatics.
ibooks
http://www.py4inf.com/code
http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy/
http://allendowney.com/
```

Updated code for urllib:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'https://www.py4e.com/book.htm'

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

Comment: How would I do it if I kept urllib and want to use request.add_header?

Comment: I removed the SSL certification parts because they are not used anymore. Can you please explain why adding headers works?

Comment: @Vince [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string are send when you are browsing a website from your computer/mobile. When you are web scraping it uses default User Agent which are generally blocked by some websites. So its like tricking the site in making it believe that you are accessing site from a different device by using [custom User Agent](https://webscraping.com/blog/User-agents/) and sending them in the header.